# Using a USA charger in Europe

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

I am about to buy an Apple charger on Ebay coming from USA, yet I am not sure if I can use it here in Europe, more precisely in Portugal.

I'm not concerned with the plug itself since I have the plug from my old broken charger and given that I can easily detach and attach it to the new charger this is not a problem.

My concern is related to the different electrical system used in USA and in Europe, so do I need to buy a converter or is it safe to use it ?

Best regards,

Filipe Silva.

Answer (score 6):

If it’s a genuine Apple charger, you should be fine, those are universal. If it’s not (and it’s not unheard of for counterfeit items to be sold on eBay), all bets are off.

See for instance Ken Shiriff’s teardowns of iPhone chargers to see what enormous differences there can be among charger designs and their safety: http://www.righto.com/2012/10/a-dozen-usb-chargers-in-lab-apple-is.html

Answer (score 2):

Apple Charges are universal (worldwide)

Every charger has a label that has to say something as following:

110-220 Volt (or 100-240 Volt)

50- 60Hz.

Then it is a Universal charger.

FYI: The USA system is 110 Volt 60 Hz while the European is 220 Volt 50 Hz.

And Apple charger covers both systems. And you do not need a expensive converter or some traveler kit for $50. All you need is $3 US to Portugal plug that you have already.

Comment: Yup, as long as the local electrical system is in range of the charger's label, all is well.

Answer (score 2):

Apple sells a "World Travel Adapter Kit" that fits most of the Apple chargers sold in the last five or so years.  The kit also includes a USB charger that fits each of the adapters.
You can use any Apple charger that fits this kit, anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no problem, I've been using mine (both the 85W and the 60W) both in Europe and the U.S. just by swapping the plug, never had any issues.